# How to download from SVN repository from behind a firewall

Tags: svn

I work behind a firewall. The firewall is configured to allow http/https only from internet explorer(not even FF or chrome). I want to download from a remote SVN repository.

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/shiro/trunk

I can browse the files from IE, but I want to download the full trunk as a zip file. Does anyone know if there is a solution for this

Comment: Guys thanks for the answers. I finally decided to go with Chris's recomendation.

Comment: Please do not add an answer just to say what you did. You can edit your question. Also, accept the answer you found best (click on checkmark).

Comment: @sleske - The OP hasn't associated his(?) SO and SU accounts, so doesn't have ownership of the question yet.

Comment: @Murali - if you associate your accounts, you'll be able to accept the answer too.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use wget.  Its in nearly all linux distros.  On windows, you can get the utility as a part of a a cygwin install, or download the [win32 port of common unix utils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).

The command to download this is

```
wget -r -I /repos/asf/incubator/shiro/trunk/ https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/shiro/trunk/
```

This tells wget to get the URL you linked recursively (-r) but only include the specified folder (-I).

wget works in this case because of the simple layout of Apache's svn repository browser.  Other svn web interfaces wouldn't allow this to work.

EDIT: If you can ONLY browse with IE, I would guess they're checking the user-agent on outbound requests.  Try the following command which mimics IE's user-agent string.

```
wget -r -U "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0b; Windows NT 6.0)" -I /repos/asf/incubator/shiro/trunk/ https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/shiro/trunk/
```

If this is still blocked by your firewall, then you're probably screwed and will be stuck right-clicking and saving each file manually.

Comment: -1 The question specifically mentions that HTTP access is restricted to using IE.

Comment: Also, I should say ChrisF's response is probably the best.  Take it up with the official channels of communication.  Depending on the policies in place, you could possibly get yourself in serious trouble at your company if you piss off the wrong IT admin.  And if they're to the point where they are blocking all browsers except IE and filtering all ports except HTTP/HTTPS, I'd be hesitant about using something like wget as it could be taken the wrong way.  But I can't upvote on here yet, so I'm stuck with long comments.

Comment: +1 simple and good enough, through I'd use `-L -np` instead of `-I`: it will download whole tree as SVN would, but leave all parent directories and external links (see that Subersion link at end of page?) intact.

Answer (score 2):

Talk to your IT department.

Explain the problem and ask them to allow you access to the site. Get your manager to back you up if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to download the full trunk as a zip file

No, this is not possible without special setup. Even the SVN client does not directly allow this.

This question is impossible to answer without further information about your network setup / firewall.

At any rate, if your firewall is configured to only allow browsing using IE, it is probably not a good idea to try and circumvent it (even if it should be technically possible). You might be breaking access rules at your place.

Ask your network admin for a solution, that's his/her job.